# How can I add path alias to a drupal 9 view?

Tags: view, path, alias, drupal-9

In a Drupal 9 installation there is a view where nodes are listed. Now I would like to do two things.

1: add a field with the node path alias to the view.

2: add an exposed filter to filter path aliases.

Unfortunately I am not able to do this. The only way to add a field with Path alias is the field "Link to Content", which can be output as plain text.

The field is displayed, but I cannot create an exposed filter for it. The error is Column not found node.view_node.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install **Pathauto module** https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto
Then Create a pattern for allias,[This is where you can create allias for a node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDJyp.png)

Now you need to go to the view and in the field configuration of which you created a pattern with in the overwrite result there will be a field named allias copy that token and place it above.

then For the filter part go to the contextual filter and add a filter of ID then do the following configurations
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSt5B.png)

Thats how i did it, hope it helps.